# Why doesn't my javascript work in django?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, frontend

I am trying to run a simple html file using VUE framework:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vue.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        <input v-model="inputText" type="text">
        <p>You typed: {{ inputText }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello from Vue.js!',
                inputText: ''
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly fine but when I put the same html into a Django framework, the **h1** tag and the **inputText** area does not show and it only appears an input box and "You typed:". The `views.py` and `urls.py` has been modified accordingly. My html code in Django is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <title>Vue.js and Django Integration</title>
    <script src="{% static 'js/vue.min.js' %}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        <input v-model="inputText" type="text">
        <p>You typed: {{ inputText }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello from Vue.js!',
                inputText: ''
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Where is the django view ? Have you even passed that html in a django view to render ?